# Spring Auto configuration resulting in old MySQL dialect

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I created a small POC app with spring boot, using hibernate (5.2.9) and maria db (10.1.19).

I had some sql dialect issues where my create/drop table SQL was using `type=MyIasam` but resolved that locally by setting the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`, however, when I deploy to the cloud (PCF) all of the cloud profile *stuff* kicks in, and I end up with hibernate deciding its dialect is going to be `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`
this results in invalid SQL getting generated for creating new tables.

Note that I'm not really sure what else could be happening. This is a spring boot app (1.5.3) and the cloud profile is kicking in to do auto configuration. There's a bunch of properties injected. And I can't seem to get my dialect property to be respected.

This is a solid crushingly easy problem that is the escaping me.

Any ideas what I need to set, or provide as dependencies?

I tried removing all of the mysql dependencies, but then the connection string inject is `jdbc:mysql...` which i think may be part of the problem...

Comment: Have you discovered the solution? I am experiencing the same issue and I'm curious what your solution was.

Comment: I never got a really good answer to be honest. I burned all my dependencies to the ground and started over with all of the spring helpers and then things started to respect the environment variables. My guess overall is some dependency mismatch causes this behavior.